# saving file path into database after uploading in joomla

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

i'm now creating my own component in joomla 2.5.14. i had uploaded files from back end. but i cant store the file path into the database. other column values are updating but the column for uploaded file is not updating. it remains null. below shown is the line i used to update values in the db.

```
$row =& JTable::getInstance('tenders', 'Table');
if(!$row->bind(JRequest::get('post')))
{
    JError::raiseError(500, $row->getError() );
}
    $row->uploaded=JRequest::getVar( $filepath, '','post', 'string', JREQUEST_ALLOWRAW );

    if(!$row->store()){
    JError::raiseError(500, $row->getError() );
}
```

my file uploading is working perfectly. help me to add the path to db using JTable store or bind functions because i use the same for updating other columns.

Comment: If you use `var_dump($filepath)`, what do you get?

Comment: i will get the full path

Comment: And uploaded is the field name?

Comment: no uploaded is the db column name

Answer (score 0):

i solved the problem. i changed the line

`$row->uploaded=JRequest::getVar( $filepath, '','post', 'string', JREQUEST_ALLOWRAW );`

as

```
$row->uploaded=$filepath;
```

then it works well..